# Can breeze work with WebAPI Odata metadata document served in atom/xml format

Tags: breeze, asp.net-web-api-odata

I am trying to put together a POC right now for breeze calling an web API Odata service. Can breeze work with the Atom/xml format of the metadatadocument that is being served by default or should it be only in json format.

I checked the source code for web api specifically the  ODataMediaTypeFomatters and identified that the ODataPayloadKind of Metadata is not part of the JsonMediaTypeFormatter.

I tried working with the atom/xml format but the breeze client is failing for that call.

Thanks in advance,
Teja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to distinguish **metadata** format from **data** format. AFAIK, OData *metadata* is always returned as XML. There is not now and never has been a JSON format for *metadata*. And Breeze has always consumed the XML representation of metadata coming from OData sources (a task outsourced to the dataJS library as I recall).

OData supports a variety of formats for query and save data although increasingly JSON is the only one that seems to matter.

I'm guessing the problem you've experienced is that Web API OData doesn't return the complete metadata that Breeze requires. It's main defect is that it omits definition of the foreign key properties that support associations. Microsoft knows about this and promises to fix it in the future.

Meanwhile, a member of the OData team provided an easy workaround and we've put it in a nuget package to make it even easier.

You'll find this described for our [Web API OData sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/breeze-web-api-odata). That sample is included in the full Breeze download, accessible from the [Breeze DownLoad page](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download).

Finally, a question for you. ***Why did you choose to write your app with Web API OData as opposed to straight Web API?***  I'm not judging. I'm curious. We want to understand the comparative value points of these closely-related alternatives.  Thanks.

Comment: i choose OData as we already have a SL app consuming an OData service. I need to use a remote Web API OData endpoint modeled on top of a EF codefirst DbContext.so i enabled CORS support for the respective controllers. however since the first call that breeze makes is for an ODataMetadata call and since it is internally handled by ODataMetadataController i was not able to decorate it with Cors attribute. so i created a separate controller, and associated convention, inheriting ODataController and decorated it with CORS. Options call goes through with out metadata payload.

Comment: A get request in fiddler gives the payload though. so can i generate the metadata by script as mentioned in breeze docs in to js file and bypass the metadata call and work with the OData endpoint for rest of the calls?. Can you please let me know my options in this regards and some resources i can check for in this scenario.

Comment: You don't have to put the cors attribute on the method or the controller. You can set it globally for the application. See [Brock Allen's thorough treatment of Web API and CORS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx). You don't even have to use the attribute. IMPORTANT: you can't use the `ODataConventionModelBuilder` because it produces incomplete metadata. See the `EdmBuilder` described in [our Web API OData sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/breeze-web-api-odata)

Comment: And, yes, you can generate the metadata any way you can get it, capture it in a script file and use THAT as your source instead of requesting $metadata from the server. Use ["Load metadata from script"](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/load-metadata-script) for inspiration.

Comment: Hi ward, Thanks for the information. i am trying to play around one of these samples http://www.breezejs.com/samples/breeze-web-api-odata . can you please let me know if there is an open webapi odata endpoint which is cors enabled for the same to play around the remote scenario in my local environment.

Comment: when i am playing around with an webapi backed service the request for metadata goes as Get and the response includes the cors headers plus the payload. i tried with jquery too with a cors enabled webapi endpoint and it works fine. but for the webapi odata call the request is a http options request instead of get when made from breeze. is there any thing i need to consider setting in the breeze configuration for this.

Comment: this is the remote call scenario using jquery on a cors enabled webapi endpoint i am talking about which is working fine and making a get request and fetching my necessary data.

http://jsfiddle.net/ramakrishnateja/QtQ5P/12/

Comment: Hi Ward, I was able to isolate the sample that is provided in to a fiddler with out angular and views and its working fine. i fill try to figure out where i am erring in my code thanks for your time and help on this. here is the fiddle that i isolated for the OdatabreezeJSSample. i hosted it on my local server. http://jsfiddle.net/ramakrishnateja/r3KmA/

Comment: HI Ward, It might be helpful for some one else.The trick shown in the link does not include setting the EdmModel namespace to the entities namespace and by default the edmmodel is taking the namespace of the DbContext so the querying through fiddler or linqpad would not work giving a 406

Comment: Hi Ward, in my app I see that with every api call there is a call to metadata. Can we copy this metadata and serve it while creating the manager just like we can do it for json metadata? I tried this but the store was expecting json format and could not parse XML Is there any alternative to call the metadata only once?

Answer (score 0):

Right now breeze only supports json.

However please feel free to add a request for other formats to the Breeze User Voice https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions.  We do take these suggestions seriously.

Also, please take a look at the new Breeze OData sample in the Breeze sample zip.

Comment: Can you direct me to the Breeze documentation that states the following :-
Breeze supports only JSON format for the OData Metadata.